# Upgrade PHP on my mac OS X 10.5

Tags: php, macos, upgrade

I'm running on OS X 10.5 (Leopard), and I want to update the current version of PHP 5.2.15 (cli) that I have to PHP 5.3 or even 5.4.

The matter is that I need to run some PHP snippets in my terminal, and the version that i have (*PHP 5.2.15 (cli) (built: May  5 2011 18:56:00)*) can't allow some functions. That's why I need to upgrade my current version.

I searched on the web, but didn't find anything. How can I do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Step 2. install [Homebrew-php](https://web.archive.org/web/20130809154123/https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php)

Step 3. install the php version you want

Step 4. happy php coding.

Alternatively, if you can't get this working (shouldn't be a problem but just in case), you can try using [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/mac/).

Comment: It seems that i'm unable to install Homebrew-php on Leopard (10.5). And installing MAMP won't help me, because I need to run those PHP snippets in my terminal.

However, thanks alot !

Comment: You can use MAMP's php from the terminal, it's located in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/php` (with 5.x.x replaced with the php version that your mamp comes with - they update it regularly). You can either add that to the front of your $PATH or symlink it to somewhere that's already in your path..

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't update the default PHP version but rather install it in, I believe its `tmp` in MacOSX. Download the source from PHP's website, then do the normal command line unzipping which is fairly easy to find online. The file itself knows where to put everything. And then just make sure that your path can point to that new PHP installation.

By typing `which php-filename' you can see if it already is in your path or not. Hope that gives you a bit of a better idea.

EDIT: Ok I correct my previous part on it being `/tmp`. From what I see its `/var`. Thats where OSX has defaulted new installations. This is what you should be doing as to not mess with the built in stuff. You never know when you might need it.

Comment: Unpacking the PHP source code into `/tmp` does not install it.

Comment: @duskwuff Haha well I know this. If you read closely I didn't say that. I said I believe it goes in tmp (more specifically tmp/bin). I can't be too sure because I'm not at my computer, but by default OSX defaults putting that info into that directory. You can unzip it in desktop and run the installer there and it will default putting it there. That's been my experience. If I am completely wrong please put your own answer and help the person looking for the help...

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are, in fact, completely wrong. `/tmp` is the temporary directory; its contents are cleared when the machine reboots. Installing software to `/tmp` will not work very well at all.

Comment: Again, put your own answer please.